# Gradient field plot of $3(x+y)^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can we draw a gradient field plot of $3(x+y)^2$

What should be the generalized approach?

Sorry I can't show any work because I can't initiate this question. I know how to plot $F(x,y)=(0,-x)$ type of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to visualize the gradient field is to draw *field lines*. They are given by the relation $$v_xdy=v_ydx$$ where, in your case, the vector field is $v=\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}2(x+y)^2,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}2(x+y)^2 \right)$.

Calculate $v_x$ and $v_y$, insert them into the first equation, integrate and plot them for some choice of the integration constant to get a visualization of the flow of the field. Try it and see what I mean and try to make sense of it - if it is still a bit confusing after that, please let me know in the comments and I'll walk you through it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit after the integration step?

Comment: @H.P.Das Sure! So now that you've integrated both sides, you have some integration constant (actually you had two, but let's just combine them into one). Now you have (or you can rewrite it to) an equation of the form $y=f(x,c)$; now plot this several times, each with a different constant ($c$).

Comment: @H.P.Das Did that make sense, or should I flesh it out by editing my answer?